# Корень слова "привычка"

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Интересно было бы узнать, каково происхождение корня таких слов как "привычка", "чрезвычайный". Этот корень явно старославянский, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Корень *ук*, тот же что и в *наука*, *навык*, *обычай*.